# Dell desktop mysteriously slows down whole LAN network when connected to a ZyXEL PK5001Z router

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a new (purchased 9-11-15) [Dell Inspiron 3647](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-3647-small-desktop/pd) desktop computer running Windows 10 (that came with McAfee LiveSafe Consumer antivirus) with a [ZyXEL PK5001Z](http://www.zyxel.com/us/en/products_services/pk5001z.shtml?t=p&tabOrder=2) wireless router that I lease from my ISP that is hard wired through an Ethernet cable to the Dell. The speed of the Wi-Fi connections for my work laptop and other family members devices is fine until someone gets on the wired Dell Inspiron 3647 computer and hits the web.

Then the Wi-Fi connections get super slow and sometimes even disconnect. The person on the Dell does not have to be doing anything big - not streaming or downloading or anything like that, just surfing the web and I am down to a crawl on my work laptop running off the wireless.

I’ve worked with my ISP and we did switch channels on the router and that seems to have helped minimize the dropped connections but the speed issue is still there.  Anyone have any ideas on what is causing the speed issue (the router, the PC, something else?) or fixes?

Comment: Run a virus/malware scan on the Dell. It's likely that it has been compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the driver for the network card on the Dell.  If you're able to update the firmware on the ZyXEL, try that too.

Dell support should be able to help you updating the driver for your network card if you're not sure how to do it.

If those steps don't work, your ISP may have a different option for wireless router they could give you to try.